# Use input from textfield to create an URL

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

Since @anywhere is no longer supported, I'm looking for a nice way to let people send tweets directly from a page without a Twitter Widget.

It is possible to create an URL which fills in the text for a tweet:

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello+this+is+a+test+message

Is there a way to make an input field and let the filled in text be converted to an text+text+text format. By submitting this filled in text it will link to the type of URL mentioned above.

So if I type in the words: 'I love you guys!' Submitting will result in linking to: 
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I+love+you+guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!

```
<input type="text" name="msg" /><button>Tweet!</button>

<script>
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var msg = document.querySelector('input[name=msg]').value.replace(/ /g, '+');
        location.href = 'https://twitter.com/tweet.php?text=' + msg;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! The only change it needs is changing 'tweet.php?text' to just 'tweet?text'.

Answer (score 0):

split("match").join("replace") - which seems counter-intuitive but it manages to work that way in most modern browsers.

in your case I think you can do `string =split(" ").join('+')` .to take entered string in text+text+text form